# When installing RubyCocoa, I got the error "error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3"

Tags: objective-c, ruby, macos

I want to install RubyCocoa. I am proceeding with the following steps.

```
% brew install ruby
・Add /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin to the path
% ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]
% git clone https://github.com/rubycocoa/rubycocoa.git
% cd rubycocoa
% gem install rake-compiler xcjobs
% rake
../../../../ext/rubycocoa/OverrideMixin.m:303:17: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected 0, have 3
  ret = (*simp)(rcv, method, arg0);
        ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../../ext/rubycocoa/OverrideMixin.m:317:13: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected 0, have 3
    (*simp)(rcv, method, arg0);
    ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
11 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [OverrideMixin.o] Error 1
rake aborted!
```

I got many warnings, but these are the only two errors.  Could you tell me how to fix it?

EDIT: These are the corresponding functions in `OverrideMixin.m:299`:

```
static id imp_methodSignatureForSelector (id rcv, SEL method, SEL arg0)
{
  id ret;
  IMP simp = super_imp(rcv, method, (IMP)imp_methodSignatureForSelector);
  ret = (*simp)(rcv, method, arg0);
  if (ret == nil)
    ret = [get_slave(rcv) methodSignatureForSelector: arg0];
  return ret;
}

static id imp_forwardInvocation (id rcv, SEL method, NSInvocation* arg0)
{
  IMP simp = super_imp(rcv, method, (IMP)imp_forwardInvocation);
  id slave = get_slave(rcv);

  if ([slave respondsToSelector: [arg0 selector]])
    [slave forwardInvocation: arg0];
  else
    (*simp)(rcv, method, arg0);
  return nil;
}
```

Comment: Searching for "imp type too many arguments to function call" on Google may lead you to an answer (no guarantees, but this looks to be the core issue).

Comment: Found the following comment: "In objc.h, unless OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES is defined, then IMP will now be typed differently to have void parameters. Sounds like that setting may be changed in newer cocoapods versions. CPTAnimation really should be fixed though.". Source: https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/147